# libcurl in iOS with IPv6

Tags: ios, curl, libcurl, ipv6

The only other thread I could find on this topic (which didn't really help) was this:

https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/594

I'm using libcurl to make API calls to a server. It works fine with IPv4 but as soon as I switch to using WiFi over a IPv6 network, I get a `CURL_COULDNT_CONNECT`.

I tried to debug to get extra info doing this:

```
curl_easy_setopt( m_curl, CURL_VERBOSE, 1L );
curl_easy_setopt( m_curl, CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION, my_trace );
```

Question 1: Is there another way to get more verbose output than checking `data` in `my_trace(CURL* handle, curl_infotype type, char* data, size_t size, void* userp )`?

Question2: Checking `data` above gives me this: `"Immediate connect fail for aa.bb.cc.dd: Network is unreachable\n"`, where the aa.bb.. is some IP. Why does it fail with IPv6?

Answer (score 2):

"Immediate connect fail for aa.bb.cc.dd" because this is an IPv4 address not an IPV6 address (which will look like aa:bb::cc:dd:... ) You need to use NAT64 to get the IPv6 address first then connect to that address

Comment: On iOS if you need to connect to an IPv4 literal address you still need to do a DNS lookup on that address so that iOS can convert it to an IPv6 address for you. Curl probably doesn't do that, so you'll need to do it yourself. The much better solution is to use a hostname and let DNS do all the hard work for you.

Comment: Yes if the address has a hostname it will be much easier. But in my case the address doesn't have a hostname :(

Comment: Then register a domain name for a few dollars/euros/etc a year and make one! There are plenty of cheap DNS registrars who have a web based DNS admin and everything for very little money these days.

Comment: I wasn't using literals just to be clear. I'm passing curl a hostname, and it successfully resolved it to the right IPv4 address before failing to connect. I think it's probably because I'm trying to connect to a IPv4 address in a IPv6 only network, and curl isn't supporting this.

Comment: @Ash You can't connect directly to an IPv4 address with IPv6. For this to work there must be NAT64 in the network. You can [set up a test NAT64 network on your Mac following Apple's directions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW16). In a live network, the mobile carrier will provide the NAT64.